# iOS can we create storyboard to landscape?

Tags: ios, storyboard, landscape-portrait

I am working on iPad project and I need to create a new storyboard or a new view controller for landscape mode so when the user change the device orientation the view controller change.

Can someone tell me if it is possible and if yes how?
if no, what we can do in this situation.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Check Attribute Inspector in IB, there you can set Orientation under 'Simulated Metrics'.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, using [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) and [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a better way of going around this - and you can also use the preview that Xcode gives you:

*Preview* -> *Main.storyboard (Preview)*

- which allows you to set a layout while seeing your results on different screen sizes and orientations automatically. (with assistant editor).

Hope this helps!